# Sending a MDNS request using Objective C sockets

Tags: ios, objective-c, sockets, bonjour, mdns

I have an iPad that will not "see" bonjour devices on the network.  So I want to send an UDP MDNS packet so that the network will give the IP the latest devices on the network so that I can perform mirroring on the iPad.  I am able to create a socket but the data I am sending is not correct.  Any ideas?

```
struct icmphdr
    {
        u_int16_t qr;       /* type sub-code */
        u_int16_t opcode;
        u_int16_t aa;
        u_int16_t tc;
        u_int16_t rd;
        u_int16_t ra;
        u_int16_t z;
        u_int16_t ad;
        u_int16_t cd;
        u_int16_t rcode;
        u_int16_t q_count;
}
// Create the socket connection
    int sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

// Configure the port and ip we want to send to
    struct sockaddr_in broadcastAddr; // Make an endpoint
    memset(&broadcastAddr, 0, sizeof (broadcastAddr));
    broadcastAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    broadcastAddr.sin_len = sizeof(broadcastAddr);
    broadcastAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    broadcastAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("224.0.0.251");
    broadcastAddr.sin_port = htons(5353); // Set port 5353

    bind (sd, (struct sockaddr *)&broadcastAddr, sizeof(broadcastAddr));
    struct icmphdr req;
    req.qr=00;      // Reponse: Message is query
    req.opcode=00;  // Opcode: Standard Query (0)
    req.tc=00;      // Truncated: Message is not truncated
    req.rd=00;      // Recursion desired: Don't do query recursively
    req.z=00;       // Z: reserved (0)

    req.ad=00;      // Non-authenticated data: Unacceptable
    req.ra=02;      // Questions: 2
    req.cd = 00;
    req.rcode = 00;
    req.q_count = 00;
    req.aa = 00;

    if (sendto(sd, &req, sizeof(req), 00, (struct sockaddr*)&broadcastAddr, sizeof broadcastAddr)) {
        NSLog(@"%s",strerror(errno));
    }
    close(sd);
```

Answer (score 1):

first - how do you know your iPad is not seeing Bonjour devices? unless it's on a very early version of iOS, it should be able to.

second - Bonjour queries are (usually) done with DNS requests for PTR records, not ICMP. AFAIK there is no way of getting a list of *every* Bonjour device on the network. so you can either ask for the services you're interested in, or query for _services._dns-sd._udp.local in order to get a list of services, then query for each of those.

either way your packet needs some question info. google for DNS packet structure, here's a quick guide to a PTR request --

id - 2 bytes, always zero
flags - 2 bytes, zero for a request
question count - 2 bytes, in this case 1
answer count - 2 bytes, zero
authority count - 2 bytes, zero
additional count - 2 bytes, zero

next comes your question -
name (eg _airport._tcp.local) - in 3www6google3com0 format
type - 2 bytes, 12 for PTR type
class - 2 bytes, 1 for internet class

that ought to do it.

note however, that before you go to this trouble, see whether you can bind() to port 5353. it won't let me do it, says the address is in use. i suppose the guys who ported the MDNS responder to iOS forgot to set the "reuse address" option on their socket. so that's the end of that. thanks guys.

Comment: Actually, you can bind to port 5353.  Here is the code to do it// Set socket option to reuse port 5353
    if (setsockopt (sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, &on, sizeof (on)) < 0) {
        NSLog (@"setsockopt() failed: %s", strerror(errno));
    }
    
    // Bind port 5353 to the iPad
    if(bind (sd, (struct sockaddr *)&client, sizeof(client)) < 0){
        NSLog(@"Binding failed: %s",strerror(errno));
    }

Comment: the first binder of a port has to set the reuse-port option for further binds to work. if the first binder doesn't, there can be no subsequent binds. tell me about it, all my mDNS apps broke with Yosemite as the new discovery thing doesn't set the option. i hear however that El Capitan goes back to mDNSResponder which does (unless they've now broken that too) set the reuse option. whew! life ain't simple for us mDNS types.